# Питон зависает при записи в файлы в папке Desktop

Tags: python, python-3.x

**UPD Проблема решена**

Симптомы исчезли после chkdsk /f и перезагрузки компьютера. Cпасибо @andreymal

**Описание проблемы**

Мне нужно заменять определенные байты в файле на другие байты. Скрипт работал исправно и долго, но сегодня столкнулся с тем, что скрипт зависает. Причем зависание происходит после обработки 10-20 файлов.

Python 3.10. Система Windows 10. Антивирус только Windows defender — отключен.

Покопавшись, я понял, что проблема с функциями **file.seek()** и **file.write()**. **Если убрать любую из них, то зависаний нет.**

Я пробовал запускать код с разными файлами из разных мест и кажется, что проблема не с конкретными видами файлов.

**Код воспроизведения ошибки**

```py
root = ...
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            file = os.path.join(path, name)
            print('1')
            with open(file, 'r+b') as f: #Здесь зависание
                print('2')
                f.seek(1)
                f.write(b'\x0a')
```

Зависание происходит на 10-20 файле между выводами "1" и "2".
Есть идеи в чем может быть проблема? Как ее отловить?

UPD.

1. Пробовал разные файлы (формата .bin, .css, .txt). Объем у файлов от 1 до 5 КБ. Более того, если удалить файл, на котором происходит зависание, то зависание будет на другом. А если удалить первые 5 файлов. То те, на которых скрипт зависал, он теперь успешно изменит... но зависнет через 10-15 файлов.
2. Замена with() на open() + close() не помогает.

UPD: Костыли для обхода проблемы

- Запустить командную строку от админа. Запустить в ней скрипт.
- Перенести файлы вне папки 'Desktop' — рабочий стол. Если путь лежит через неё, то блокируется запись на 10-20 файле. **Почему? Пока не могу найти ответа**

**UPD Проблема решена**

Симптомы исчезли после chkdsk /f и перезагрузки компьютера. Cпасибо @andreymal

Comment: Как именно вы определяете зависание? Пробовали ставить принт внутри цикла, например?

Comment: @andreymal Добавил в код место зависания — оно происходит на 10-20 проходе цикла между выводами "1" и "2".

Comment: А какой файл при этом открывается?

Comment: @andreymal любой. Если удалить тот, на котором было зависание, то зависнет уже на другом. Важно, что перед зависаниям скрипт проходит по 10-20 файлам объемом от 1 до 5 Кбайт.

Comment: Есть антивирус? Может, он считает это подозрительной активностью?

Comment: @andreymal думал о таком. Windows defender отключен. Журнал событий у него пуст.

Comment: Все в одном потоке выполняется?

Comment: @dtroyan да. Скрипт снова заработал, когда я запустил его сперва запустив командную строку от админа. Почему-то требуются какие-то продвинутые админ права. У меня отключен антивирус и никаких сообщений не пишется о подозрительной активности и проч. Как система блочит исполнение файла я так и не понял.

Comment: а попробуйте with заменить дедовским методом

Comment: @dtroyan да попробовал через open+close. Все тоже самое. Оказывается причина в том, что файлы расположены в Desktop папке. Непонятно почему такое поведение.

Comment: Глупое предложение, но вдруг — а если выполнить проверку диска? (с перезагрузкой)

Comment: @andreymal Гениально. chkdsk /f и перезагрузка устранили проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее зависание при создании файлового дескриптора на диске, запрещенная область или медленный диск. Также антивирус сисетмы может блокировать вызовы большого колличества файлов или шина диска не расчитана на открытие 20 дескрипторов и время уходит на их заморозку

Comment: Проблема уже решена, посмотрите комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: всё-таки интересно: исходя из каких соображений в слове «количество» пишут две буквы «л»? это очень распространённая ошибка, на банальную опечатку вину никак не свалишь. какая-то логика тут должна быть.